# How to integrate react native application with spring boot oauth2

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, oauth-2.0

I have spring boot application that has oauth2 configuration as you can see below:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: clientIdValue
            clientSecret: clientSecretValue
            redirectUri: "https://localhost/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - email
              - profile
          facebook:
            clientId: clientIdValue
            clientSecret: clientSecretValue
            redirectUri: "https://localhost/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - email
              - public_profile
        provider:
          facebook:
            authorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth
            tokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token
            userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
```

Now, i have a react-native application that uses [google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin) plugin to signin with google. how can i integrate this react-native app to works with spring boot application in signin/signup?

As you can see in [google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin) plugin, it doesn't have any callback or redirect url in options.

Comment: Yes, i answered my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve this problem without using any plugin, just when user touched the google or facebook login, i redirected user to google or facebook, for example to `https://localhost/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=https://localhost/oauth2/redirect`.

After authorization completed i checked that user comes from mobile or not (using user agent info) and if it was true i redirected user to `myapp://accessToken/{{token_value_from_google_or_facebook}}`, with this redirection my mobile application opened and every thing is OK.